# How can I find the height of a dynamically created table row element with no height set?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, html-table

I have two tables adjacent to each other both being populated dynamically in C#, I want both of these two tables to have the corresponding row height be exactly the same depending on what the first tables row height is (no specific height has been set, just needs to fit text in).

I have tried various ways of getting the height in C#, javascript, jquery, etc however they all return null or 0, i can get it to work by actively setting the height however this is not very effecient and occasionally buggy, is there a way I can get the height of a dynamically created html table row/cell?

Comment: can you show how the tables are being created.. are you familiar with `CSS` or try this `Jquery` site.. http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: For both adjacent tables to have the same row height, you might use a CSS only solution. Just create a single HTML table but style it as to look as two separated tables side by side. This way, "both" table rows will share the same height.

Answer (score 1):

@JoseRuiSantos comment is a better implementation if your design allows it (i.e. combine data in both tables in to a single table and accordingly render rows and columns to display as two different tables using css).

One way I could think is to try using javascript:
For this to work, do not set any table/row/column heights in both tables.
Add an empty column at the end of each table with a div element in it. In the page load completed event, identify the max column height in corresponding row of both tables and set the corresponding div element's (in both tables) height (in corresponding row) to the column max height.